# Angular ui-router: adding templateUrl breaking routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having an issue where once the `templateUrl` is added into the `ui-router` child state, the application will no longer perform the routing to the state. It works fine when it's just a template.

**app.js**:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page-not-found');

        $stateProvider
                .state('dashboard', {
                    url: '/',
                    views: {
                        'header': {
                            template: 'header'
                        },
                        'nav': {
                            template: 'nav'
                        },
                        main: {
                            template: 'You are on the homepage'
                        }
                    }
                });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

app.run(['$rootScope', 'userService', '$state', function ($rootScope, user, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));

    if (!user.exists) {
        $state.go('user.reg');
    }
}]);
```

**User.states.js**:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
            .state('user', {
                url: '/users',
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    'header': {},
                    'nav': {},
                    'main': {
                        template: '<ui-view/>'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('user.reg', {
                url: '/register',
                //template: 'This will show fine',
                templateUrl: '/app/Users/User.login.html' // this will break
            });

}]);
```

**UPDATE**

If I add a `ui-sref="user.reg"` to my initial pages I can navigate to the state/page fine, with the `templateUrl` and `template` . So its just an issue when I try to use `state.go('user.reg');`

This means a work around is using the `$location` provider to change the path. Has the same effect but does seem rather wrong

Comment: When it breaks do you see console errors? is it 404 for the template url path?

Comment: @Starscream1984 No errors at all, the file is present and does not 404. It is not even routing to the user.register state, just staying at the index state

Comment: Only difference I can see between your example and a working example I have, is that in my code, there isn't a leading slash in the url string...

Comment: @Starscream1984 I get the same effect after removing it. What version of angular/ ui-router are you using?

Comment: angular - v1.4.7     ui-router - v0.2.15

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your relative paths.

Look at this code:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

You have html5 mode enabled, and for that to work, you have your base ref set in your html, which probably looks like this:

```
<base href="/">
```

Your issue is likely that the route for your template isn't "yoursite.com/app/Users/User.login.html."

[See this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KHYcPeNMPXbX3RyGCTU8) for a working version of your code. Then go into the html code and uncomment out the base tag, and notice that it will break.

Comment: The template is in the correct location, so that's not the issue